# Error: Live editing has been turned off

Tags: umbraco

When trying to use 'Edit in Canvas' function in Umbraco I see the following error message:

> Umbraco Canvas requires an ASP.Net form to function properly. Live
>   editing has been turned off.

Comment: You answered your own question within a second ?

Comment: I opened it as a question with an answer as I found the answer on another forum - figured I'd add it to the stack as it may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable canvas editing you must ensure your page includes a form set to `runat=server`

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
...
</form>
```